# How do I Configure remote debugging in Sublime text 3 to connect with sketchup Ruby API

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, sketchup

I want the way to configure Sublime to  connect Sketchup Ruby API debugger to have auto-completion and intellisense in Sublime text 3 .

Comment: This question is **far** too broad. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. [`SublimeCodeIntel`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeCodeIntel) works quite well for Ruby autocompletion.

Comment: I want to reflect the API classes in the intellisense , and send and retrieve text from Sketchup ruby console into Sublime .

Comment: Good for you. Have fun!